# Proof quantal response with infinite lambda converges to a "pure" utility maximization

Tags: utility

In quantal response model, when λ -> ∞, quantal response converges to a "pure" utility maximization.
I can understand it intuitively, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Comment: Check the proof of Theorem 2 in McKelvey and Palfrey (1995): http://www.dklevine.com/archive/refs4510.pdf.